# screen record of android device for all version below to kitkat

Tags: java, android

i want to screen record the android device for all version .
i have used the code for screen

```
Process su;

su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

outputStream.writeBytes("screenrecord --time-limit 10 /sdcard/MyVideo.mp4\n");
outputStream.flush();

outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
outputStream.flush();

su.waitFor();
```

it record the screen but give the video size is **null** or **0kb** in size and when play show message can't be played . please  any one update . i have try many solution but not get perfect solution. thank in advance

Comment: You can't record screen without root access. Period!

Comment: i have make a root with SRSRoot tool but till not play the video

Comment: i have also check the device rooting by play store app and now my device show is rooted

Answer (score 0):

If you want to screen recording then must root your device.
without root screen recording not possible.

Thanks,
Girish

Comment: yes i have rooted the device the SRSRoot for android Tool. but screen video is recode but size is 0 kb

Comment: any one can tell me how to save the screen recorded video programatically as i save the video using cmd commands by Ctrl+c